# How to define css animation?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have written this code to make a rectangle move from left to right like a car but this is not working. I think there is problem with `@keyframes` example

```css
* {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.road {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    top: 20%;
    left: 80%
  }
  20% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 60%
  }
  40% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%
  }
  60% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%
  }
  80% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%
  }
  to {
    top: 20%;
    left: 0%
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 80%
  }
  20% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 60%
  }
  40% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%
  }
  60% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%
  }
  80% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%
  }
  100% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 0%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes example {
  0% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 80%
  }
  20% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 60%
  }
  40% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%
  }
  60% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%
  }
  80% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%
  }
  100% {
    top: 20%;
    left: 0%
  }
}

.car {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 100px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: example;
  -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: Edit the code please. Try to put everything in a single wrapper.

Comment: Here is a link to animation and transition css https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/transitions-animations/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position: relative` on `.car` to be displayed like that.

```
.car {
    position: relative;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 100px;

    animation-name:example;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -webkit-animation-name: example;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -moz-animation-name: example;
    -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to move the car as if it were absolutely positioned. Make sure you have a wrapper that the car is inside of (In this case I'm assuming it's the road) and give that a relative position. Give you're car an absolute position. Here's a codepen I created that may help you!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdYLOM

Also try making your animation like this:

```
@keyframes example {
  0% { left: 0% }
  100% { left: 100% }
}
```